# Get json data from file in es6

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I have a problem with get json data from file.
I have an error 404 (Not found) in console. I dont know what is wrong, when i put url instead of a file path its works

```
export const loadProducts = {
    init: function () {
        this.getFromJson();
    },

    getFromJson: function() {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('GET', '../data/products.json', true);

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.status == 200){
                console.log('data')
                const files = JSON.parse(request.response);
            } 
            else {
                console.log('connected, but API returned an error');
            }
        };

        request.onerror = function() {
            console.log('connection error');
        };

        request.send(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest will not read from the file system -- it will try to read from `localhost` in this case. Do you need to read from the file system?

Comment: How are you opening / running this script; in a browser or console via node?

Comment: If you're going to use `onreadystatechange` you **must** check `request.readyState` is `4` (or `XMLHttpRequest.DONE`) before attempting to check `status` and `responseText`

Comment: Yes, I need read this from file system.

Comment: If you want to use file system, don't you want to try nodejs instead, refs: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html ? it does provide file system api out of the box.
refers to this question: there's thorough explanation on writing or reading files in one of the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try it. It works for me.

```js
export const loadProducts = {
  init: function() {
    this.getFromJson();
  },

  getFromJson: function() {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requeest.overrideMimeType("application/json");

    let path = 'file:///C:/folder/blah.json';

    request.open('GET', 'file:///C:/some/file.json', true);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == "200") {
        console.log('data')
        const files = JSON.parse(request.response);
      } else {
        console.log('connected, but API returned an error');
      }
    };

    request.onerror = function() {
      console.log('connection error');
    };

    request.send();
  }

}
```

P.s. XMLHttpRequest works with `file` protocol. Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)